# Sudden error with wordpress with nginx only (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input)

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, wordpress, php-fpm

I've installed Wordpress on my VPS and is run smoothly with apache2. But recently , I recognized that it consume too much RAM (~600MB for 7-8 session) so I decided to change to Nginx. After changing for few days, it's working fine, without any problem but suddenly yesterday, the Admin Page layout was destroyed. I looked into the console log and found out this problem: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input, the file was wp-admin/load-scripts.php.

You can access to the file as

http://vietnammechkey.com/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,json2&ver=3.8.2 [Nginx]

http://vietnammechkey.com:8888/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,json2&ver=3.8.2 [Apache2]

The file will be longer if I use Apache2 and it will be sorter if I use nginx

Note: The Wordpress working perfectly on Apache2.

Comment: The JQuery code seems corrupted on this page. Is it exactly the same page (in same directory) served by Apache and NGinx ?

Comment: Yes, it is. When I switch to apache, it worked perfect.

Comment: Is `php-fpm` daemon still running ?

Comment: yes, there are about 4-5 processes named php5-fpm

Comment: I am confused by the very first line in both files : have look. Are you sure you didn't change anything in the NGinx virtual host config ? imho `/home/web/Sites/public_html//wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js` has nothing to do here in the file served by NGinx

Comment: Oh that was the line I added to test, I've just removed

Comment: Please pastebin these or add them in-line in your question. I'm getting a 403 error and temporary links make this question useless for future visitors.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm trying to install lighttpd... You can access it now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved, nginx can't acces to it's buffer folder "/var/lib/nginx". Just chmod 0755 and it's working fine now

Comment: If you don't change the default user which nginx run with, this problem would not happen AFAIK. or make it like this `user nginx nginx` which is the group name and user name respectively.

Comment: In my case it wasn't the permissions, but rather the ownership. For nginx I'm using "sites" as the owner, and "nginx" as the group in my configuration, so running `chown -R sites:nginx /var/lib/nginx` fixed the problem for me.